# Spring Boot 1.5.2 sample returns 404

Tags: java, spring

So I pulled down the [Spring Boot Sample Web JSP](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp) example. I imported into Eclipse and I tweaked the POM so that it pulled in the parent POM properly but everything else is untouched. But when I hit the URL I get a 404. Below is the POM and is the only thing I've changed. I'm using Eclipse Luna to run it as a Spring App. The log didn't seem to show anything other than resource not found. Verified that the controller's method is getting called, so it's after the "welcome" view name being returned.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <!-- Your own application should inherit from spring-boot-starter-parent -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-sample-web-jsp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Spring Boot Web JSP Sample</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Web JSP Sample</description>
    <url>http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/</url>
    <organization>
        <name>Pivotal Software, Inc.</name>
        <url>http://www.spring.io</url>
    </organization>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>
        <m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>/</m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Compile -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Provided -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And this is a snippet of my log

```
.w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : Method [sample.jsp.WelcomeController.welcome] returned [welcome]
o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Requested media types are [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [*/*])
o.s.w.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver  : No matching bean found for view name 'welcome'
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'welcome'
o.s.w.s.v.InternalResourceViewResolver   : Cached view [welcome]
o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Returning [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'welcome'; URL [/WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp]] based on requested media type 'text/html'
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'welcome'; URL [/WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            : Rendering view with name 'welcome' with model {time=Wed Mar 15 13:59:42 EDT 2017, message=Hello Phil} and static attributes {}
o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            : Added model object 'time' of type [java.util.Date] to request in view with name 'welcome'
o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            : Added model object 'message' of type [java.lang.String] to request in view with name 'welcome'
o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            : Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'welcome'
o.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper   :   Returning non-STM instance
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@1077e52
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp]
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping@6cee48] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : No handler mapping found for [/WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp]
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping@190641d] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp
o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : getResource(org/springframework/mail/javamail/mime.types)
o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :   Delegating to parent classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@a4be02
o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findResource(org/springframework/mail/javamail/mime.types)
o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     --> Resource not found, returning null
o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :   --> Resource not found, returning null
.PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy : Loading default Java Activation Framework FileTypeMap
javax.activation                         : MimetypesFileTypeMap: load HOME
javax.activation                         : MimetypesFileTypeMap: load SYS
javax.activation                         : MimetypesFileTypeMap: load JAR
o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       :     findResources(META-INF/mime.types)
```

Comment: I pulled down the 1.3.8.RELEASE version and this works just fine. So my build process is ok. But I have no clue as to what the difference between 1.5.2 and 1.3.8 would cause this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `<scope>provide</scope>` element of `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` and `tomcat-embed-jasper`.
I met this problem too and it fix my issue by doing that.

Comment: Sounded promising. But I made the change to both dependencies, did a Maven|Update Project and rebuilt and still gives me a 404. It's probably something very similar and related to what you suggest.